# SSRS Expression to near Monday of last Year

Tags: reporting-services, expression, ssrs-2012

In SSRS how can I write an expression to find the Monday of Last year for a date
Example: If I choose 9/26/2016 which is a Monday , I have to find 9/26/2015 is Monday or not . In this case 9/26/2015 Is Saturday , so I have to set the date parameter as the nearest Monday which is 9/21/2015
How can I do it via  an SSRS expression

```
 =DATEADD(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!BeginDate.Value)
```

This will helps to find the Last Year same date , but how can I change to make it to select the Monday of last Year

Answer (score 1):

```
=DateAdd
(
    DateInterval.Day
    , 2 - weekday(dateadd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!BeginDate.Value))
    , dateadd(DateInterval.Year,-1,Parameters!BeginDate.Value)
)
```

To break the DateAdd function down...
The first argument is simply telling it to adjust by a number of days
The next argument gets the weekday for the parameter date minus a year, we then take this number FROM 2 (which is the weekday value for a Monday) so if the parameter date last year was a Thursday (5) we would get 2-5 which gives us -3 so we'll take three days of our date.
The final argument is the parameter date minus a year which is the date we want to subtract (in this case) 3 days from.

**NOTE** If you system setting are not default the weekdays returned may not be the same so check and adjust the `, 2-(...` part accordingly, set it to whatever Monday evaluates to.